# laravel event broadcast from inside job queue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

Its been days, i am stuck at broadcasting events.

I have 
 - AWS elastic beanstalk setup.
 - Pusher configured with following configurations
    
    `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
    QUEUE_DRIVER=database`

- Running a laravel supervisor.
- Using Laravel version **5.5**
- A Job namely `ConvertVideoForStreaming`
- An Event namely `VideoProcessingStarted`

This event gets called the the Job is started processing at backend.

It works fine with i try it locally using

`php artisan queue:work --timeout=0 --tries=1`

But when i try to use supervisor, the Job gets executed but the event called from inside job is not dispatched.

I am still not sure why it is doing that, work locally with artisan command but not with the supervisor running on aws server.

supervisor configurations for elastic beanstalk:

```
[supervisord]
   logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
   logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
   logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
   loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
   pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
   nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
   minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
   minprocs=20                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

   [rpcinterface:supervisor]
   supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

   [supervisorctl]
   serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

   [program:queue]
   command=php artisan queue:work database --tries=3 --timeout=0 --queue=notifications,default
   directory=/var/app/current
   stdout_logfile=/var/app/current/storage/logs/supervisor.log
   redirect_stderr=true
```

The Event class:**VideoProcessingStarted**

```
class VideoProcessingStarted implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $videoID;
    public $offerID;
//    public $queue = 'notifications'; //Queue Name

    public function __construct($video)
    {
        $this->videoID = $video->id;
        $this->offerID = $video->offer->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('videos-processing.'.$this->videoID);
    }
}
```

Job: **ConvertVideoForStreaming**

```
class ConvertVideoForStreaming implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $video;
    public $disk;
    public $dateTimeStringNow;

    public function __construct(OfferLibrary $video,$disk)
    {
        $this->video = $video;
        $this->disk = $disk;
        $this->dateTimeStringNow = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        /*
         * TotalJobStatuses
         * 1 - queue (meaning processing is pending)
         * 2 - processing (job has been started and in progress)
         * 3 - success (job has been processed and got completed successfully)
         * 4 - failed (job has been processed, but failed to complete)
         * */
        event(new VideoProcessingStarted($this->video));
        event(new VideoProcessingFailed($this->video->id));
        event(new VideoProcessingQueued($this->video));
        \Log::info('this should work, why not working, i dont know.::'.$this->video->id);
        return null;
}
```

the events inside jobs are totally ignored, no errors nothing.

```
event(new VideoProcessingStarted($this->video));
            event(new VideoProcessingFailed($this->video->id));
            event(new VideoProcessingQueued($this->video));
```

but this last log info line gets to be executed and is logged inside laravel.log file

```
\Log::info('this should work, why not working, i dont know.::'.$this->video->id);
```

I don't know why, but events work fine on local machine, but when i try it on supervisor on aws server, they are simply ignored from with inside jobs.

Comment: The error log is empty and the job is not in the failed jobs table?

Comment: @RolandStarke
Yes, No Errors, and the Job is executing successfully, but the events inside jobs seems like are ignored.

Comment: @RolandStarke
I also updated my question at the end.

Comment: Mm, that would be my next question, making sure the code is run you intended. (sry i can only search simple errors..... The next thing I would try, personaly, is to check if other events work or if it's a problem with broadcast events.

Comment: @RolandStarke
The same code works locally,

i feel like that the `php artisan queue:work` running through the supervisor on aws cant handle broadcast or ignores the broadcast events.

Comment: Have you tried [listening for failed job events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#failed-job-events) and logging from there?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter is never failed, thou after your commend, i tried `Queue::before` and tried logging from there the job event names, seems like, the job events are not totally ignored, Laravel does read the job events even inside the `broadcastOn` method, but does not broadcast it.